# What is the right approach for dynamically creation of SQL-queries?

Tags: design, c#, sql

**The problem:**
I have a application where the data comes from SQL tables. The design of the tables differs a bit from client to client. Example:

ClientA sells thermometers and the product has features like measuring range, sensor length and nominal size. Client A has a table 'ArticleFeatures' with the columns range, sendor length and nominal size.
ClientB sells fabric and the product has features like color, fabric type and size. Client B has a table 'ArticleFeatures' with the columns color, fabric type and size.

Those product features are designed as 'feature sets' with a unique identifier. A client can have more than one feature sets, because he sells different articles. It could also be that a client has a special database table for article characteristic like "FabricColor".

Now I want to implement a possibility for the customer to see user-defined article features from their tables and to make this customizable.

**My idea**

My idea is to create an object, that holds the information for the data creation and let the user define all the possible values. A prototype of the anonymous object in C# that holds those values:

```
            var tObject = new
            {
                ObjectID = "OBJ001",
                Matchcode = "TestObjekt",
                Scope = "Article",
                DataSources = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        ObjectID = "OBJ001",
                        DataSourceID = "DS001",
                        FromTable = "TestArticle",
                        WhereCondition = "WHERE IsActive = -1",
                        Fields = new[]
                        {
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Articlenumber",
                                Alias = ""
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Matchcode",
                                Alias = ""
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "ArticleCategory",
                                Alias = "Category"
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "IsActive",
                                Alias = ""
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        ObjectID = "OBJ001",
                        DataSourceID = "DS002",
                        FromTable = "TestArticleFeatureColor",
                        WhereCondition = "WHERE IsActive = -1",
                        Fields = new[]
                        {
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Articlenumber",
                                Alias = ""
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Description",
                                Alias = "Matchcode"
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Colorcode",
                                Alias = "Code"
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                Description = "Color",
                                Alias = ""
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                Relation = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        FirstDataSourceID = "DS001",
                        Type = "LEFT",
                        Condition = "TestArticle.Ariclenumber = TestArticleFeatureColor.Articlenumber"
                        SecondDataSourceID = "DS002"
                    }
                }
            };
```

Now I can dynamically use this data to create a data source for the representation of the data.

**Questions**

Is this a good approach? What can I improve?

Comment: I am not sure what problem you're trying to solve. Why wouldn't you just write a SQL query using the SQL language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamically generating SQL like you seem to be doing is probably not a good idea.

As far as I can see there are a few options

1. Serialize the data into a BLOB column. This lets you store any kind of data, but limits the possibility of validating and searching in the data.
2. Use a non-relational database. There are several databases for storing arbitrary objects, and may provide better performance for indexing etc. But you will lose some of the features of a relational database.
3. Use a separate table for all custom properties, with relations to the table for the article, and possibly to a table for sets of properties. This would also imply some limits on how data is verified, but should allow fast searching.
4. Use a completely unique schema for each customer. Allows the full set of relational features to be used, but would probably also require custom software for each customer.

In any case, I would recommend using an ORM that maps closely to the database model, and if needed, have a separate layer to convert this model to something else.